# React onClick Performance and Re-rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two divs and on clicking, I am setting `isVisible` state. Is there a performance difference between the two divs?

I mean in the case of **ShowDiv**, will it recreates that function on each render? Is **ShowDiv2** better than **ShowDiv** in any way or are they the same?

```
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

const showDiv = () => {
   setIsVisible(!isVisible);
}

return(
   <>
     <div onClick={() => setIsVisible(!isVisible)}>Show Div</div>
     <div onClick={showDiv}>Show Div2</div>
   </>
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any difference as far as I know, because whenever we rerender we redefine the functions, I think it is a matter of clean code and code readability.